# How to draw a solid line, that fades out to one side in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

[image]

How would you draw something like that blue border above, where there's a solid line that fades out to total transparency on one side, in GIMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple way to achieve my goal by downloading the Gimp plugin [Layer Effects](http://registry.gimp.org/node/186), which adds an inner glow effect, among others, like what I imagine Photoshop already has built-in.

Answer (score 4):

I just noticed the little GIMP tag, a quick search enabled me to find this [tutorial for creating an 'Inner Glow' type effect in GIMP](http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=6391)

The layer style `Inner Glow` in Photoshop, and equivalents in other software, will do that for you:

[image: layer style inner glow]

Comment: Thank you. Even though I went a different direction, having gotten to know the keywords "inner glow" helped me research this further.